# How "reserveCapacity" function works with "Dictionary" CollectionType in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I was checking `reserveCapacity` function with `Array` & `Dictionary` and observed this below  behaviour :-

1. In `Array` I got it perfectly :

   ```
   var array:Array<String> = Array<String>.init()

    array.reserveCapacity(2)

    print(array.capacity) // output : 2
   ```
2. In `Dictionary` its giving below result due to `"key:value"` pairing  :

   ```
   var dict:Dictionary<String,Any> = Dictionary<String,Any>.init()

     dict.reserveCapacity(2)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 3

     dict.reserveCapacity(0)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 0
     dict.reserveCapacity(1)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 1

     dict.reserveCapacity(2)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 3

     dict.reserveCapacity(3)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 3
     dict.reserveCapacity(4)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 6
     dict.reserveCapacity(5)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 6
     dict.reserveCapacity(6)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 6
     dict.reserveCapacity(7)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 12
     dict.reserveCapacity(8)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 12
     dict.reserveCapacity(9)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 12
     dict.reserveCapacity(10)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 12
     dict.reserveCapacity(11)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 12
     dict.reserveCapacity(12)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 12
     dict.reserveCapacity(13)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 24
     //.
     //.
     dict.reserveCapacity(24)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 24
     dict.reserveCapacity(25)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 48
     //.
     //.
     dict.reserveCapacity(48)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 48
     dict.reserveCapacity(49)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 96
     //.
     //.
     dict.reserveCapacity(96)
     print(dict.capacity) //output 96
   ```

Can somebody will help me to understand  `reserveCapacity` function behaviour in case of  `Dictionary` that why and how its calculating `capacity` value ?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: *"This method ensures that the dictionary has unique, mutable, contiguous storage, with space allocated for at least the requested number of key-value pairs"*; you would need to look at the source code to understand exactly what algorithm is used. It may be something to do with the bucket size

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for update, i require more simple clarification & where I will. get source code for this reserveCapacity function ? or you may simply give me a brief understanding of it's logic as well. it will be more than sufficient. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can dig through the Swift source code if you like - Dictionary uses [`DictionaryStorage`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/DictionaryStorage.swift) - The storage will be allocated based on a scale factor and the hash bucket size.

Comment: First, the parameter to `reserveCapacity` is not the “capacity”, but rather the “minimum capacity” (meaning that it is always free to reserve more space than is currently needed). Second, you will see this pattern repeatedly in Swift collections, namely that if the requested capacity exceeds the currently available capacity, it will double the capacity. The details vary, but this doubling of capacity is common (e.g., both arrays and dictionaries manifest this sort of behavior).

Comment: Thanks Rob ! but still I am not getting the behaviour of reserveCapacity function with "Dictionary" and "Set" cases. I know that   reserveCapacity will define a  “minimum capacity”.  in Array it's straight forward but in  "Dictionary" and "Set" I am not getting a proper understanding.

Comment: It's not simple for Arrays either. You only put in 2. Try other values (and multiple values) and you'll find it jumps around in surprising ways. In a quick test modifying the capacity on an Array, I got 2 => 2, 3 => 4, 12 => 12,  13 => 14, 200 => 252.

Comment: Array is not as straight forward as your example suggests. Try adding items to an array (rather than calling `reserveCapacity`) and watch how capacity changes as you go along. You’ll see behavior very reminiscent of what you’re seeing for dictionary. Bottom line, all these collection types do all sorts of well-engineered, albeit not immediately obvious, capacity management. If your question is what precisely is that logic, you might be able to deduce that from the source. But none of this behavior is remotely surprising.

Comment: I haven't dug into Swift's implementation, but a common way to do this with other systems (such as malloc) is to find an available block of memory that happens to be free and reasonably close to the size you want. So the capacity can be based on how memory has been recently allocated and freed (and therefore how it's been fragmented) in the program at runtime. (Memory allocation is a very complex topic, and has very different behaviors for blocks of different sizes.)

Comment: By the way, to make the dictionary structure conversation more complicated, note that there are different storage mechanisms. See the comments in [`Dictionary.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift). You might experience different types of capacity management algorithms based upon the type of storage backing your dictionary.

Comment: If you want to see the basic algorithm (the one used for NativeDictionary), look at [`HashTable.scale(forCapacity:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/HashTable.swift#L68-L85). Your question is good. The answer is just highly implementation dependent and subject to change. The best way to answer it is to study the implementation to learn it as deeply as you like. Swift's is public and most of the stdlib code is very approachable if you have a moderate amount of Swift experience (and it's even good for beginners to look at and learn what there is to learn).

Comment: Thanks everyone! will learn more about this.